# Rest Webservice hosted in WAS return HTML for error status codes

Tags: web-services, websphere, http-status-code-404

we are hosting rest based webservices on WAS 8.0. The issue is when we return a error status code with a message, server is adding its own HTML response and then my plain text message. Any idea on how to disable WAS server adding its own HTML

ex.
when I return

```
Response getEntity(String entityId){
...
...
...
return  Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Entity you are searching for is not found").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
}
```

the response I get is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
Entity you are searching for is not found
```

any configuration settings I must do in WAS server to avoid the HTML?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, we were accessing webervice in was via a IIS Server (reverse proxy) the HTML was getting added by the IIS not WAS. Follow instructions at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdevelopertips/2009/08/24/tip-93-did-you-know-php-and-custom-error-pages-configuration/ and the issue got resolved.